# Invariant Violation when adding a form

Tags: reactjs

**[Edit]**

Acutally, I believe my issue is due to the fact I'm in an ASP.Net application, which is generating a global `<form>` element. Thus, the `form` I'm trying to render is ignored by the browser, because nesting form is forbidden in html.

Any workaround?

**[/Edit]**

I'm making my first steps in the react world, and I'm facing an error.

I've written a small component supposed to display links and a small form to add new ones.

I can successfully display my links list, but the form itself does not works.

Here is my render method:

```
render: function () {
    return (
    <div className="myLinks-new">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="mylinks-newlinkform">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Étiquette" ref="label" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Url cible" ref="target" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Mode d'ouverture" ref="openMode" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" />
        </form>
    </div>)
    ;
```

I *think* the faulting part is the `<form>` node. If I remove it, no error. If I left it (keeping only the `<div>` node, I get in the js console:

> ``` Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `` ```.

How to solve it?

The strange thing, is that it make *another* component disappear in the result. The form itself shows in the dom, but not the link list (actually, the **first render pass** works, but I get the state from an ajax call and I call `setState`).

I don't know if it matters, but here is the call to my component:

```
render: function () {

    return (<div className="myLinks">
            <MyLinksList links={this.state.data.Links} />
            <MyLinksAddLink onAddNewLink={this.handleNewLink} />
    </div>);
}
```

The full code is :

```
var MyLinksAddLink = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var label = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.label).value.trim();
        var target = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.target).value.trim();
        var openMode = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.openMode).value.trim();

        this.props.onAddNewLink({ Label: label, Target: target, OpenMode: openMode });
        return;
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
        <div className="myLinks-new"><form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="mylinks-newlinkform">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Étiquette" ref="label" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Url cible" ref="target" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Mode d'ouverture" ref="openMode" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" />
            </form>        </div>)
        ;
    }

});
var MyLinksListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
               <li className="myLinks-list-item list-group-item">{this.props.link.Label}</li>
            );
    }

});
var MyLinksList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var i = 0;
        var linkNodes = this.props.links.map(function (link) {
            i++;
            return (
                <MyLinksListItem key={i} link={link}/>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="myLinks-list-container">
                Here will be links
                    <ul className="myLinks-list list-group">
                        {linkNodes}
                    </ul>
            </div>);

    }
});

var MyLinks = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: {
                Links: []
            }
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({ data: data });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    handleNewLink: function (link) {
        var data = this.state.data;
        data.Links.push(link);
        this.setState({ data: data })
    },
    render: function () {

        return (<div className="myLinks">
                <MyLinksList links={this.state.data.Links} />
                <MyLinksAddLink onAddNewLink={this.handleNewLink} />
        </div>);
    }
});
```

And somewhere in my page:

```
<script type='text/jsx'>React.render(<MyLinks url='/path/to/mydata' />, document.getElementById('somediv'));</script>
```

The data url is returning a payload similar to:

```
{
  "Links": [
    {
      "Label": "MyLabel",
      "OpenMode": 1,
      "Target": "http:\\/\\/www.sosp.fr"
    },
    {
      "Label": "MyLabel2",
      "OpenMode": 4,
      "Target": "http:\\/\\/www.sosp.fr\\/2"
    },
    {
      "Label": "MyLabel3",
      "OpenMode": 0,
      "Target": "http:\\/\\/www.sosp.fr\\/3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**[edit]** the generated DOM is this one (from Chrome dev tools):

```
<div class="myLinks" data-reactid=".0">
    <div class="myLinks-list-container" data-reactid=".0.0">
        <span data-reactid=".0.0.0">Here will be links</span>
        <ul class="myLinks-list list-group" data-reactid=".0.0.1"></ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Étiquette" data-reactid=".0.1.0">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Url cible" data-reactid=".0.1.1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mode d'ouverture" data-reactid=".0.1.2">     
    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" data-reactid=".0.1.3">
</div>
```

As you can see, the form has simply disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something changes the browser's DOM outside of React's control, then you'll get an `Invariant Violation` error. As you showed in the last block of generated DOM output, the `<form>` tag React is trying to manage for you has been unexpectedly removed from the DOM.

As noted in the error message, `This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to ... nesting tags like <form>`

I can't tell from the portion of the DOM that you posted, but if you're nesting `<form>` tags as your edit says, then yes, the browser will remove the inner `<form>` tag and React will throw an error.

You'll need to find a way to prevent the ASP.net framework from creating the `<form>` tag.

Comment: unfortunately, the whole application can't be changed. I'll sadly leave ReactJs (at least in this project). Thx,